# Проверка на наличие в сообщении фразы из массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Делаю бота для ВК на vkbottle
Его функция заключается в том, что он должен отвечать на сообщение если оно содержит фразу из массива. Пока получилось сделать ответ на сообщение, если оно равно любой фразе из массива

```
@bot.on.message(text=["слава коммунизм", "Слава коммунизм"])
async def hi_handler(message: Message):


    users_info = await bot.api.users.get(message.from_id)
    await message.answer("Партия гордится тобой!",  "photo-208523444_457239769")
```

Полный код:

```
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from vkbottle.dispatch.rules.base import CommandRule
from vkbottle import DocMessagesUploader
from typing import Tuple
from array import *

bot = Bot(token="token")


@bot.on.message(text=["слава коммунизм", "Слава коммунизм"])
async def hi_handler(message: Message):


    users_info = await bot.api.users.get(message.from_id)
    await message.answer("Партия гордится тобой!",  "photo-208523444_457239769")


@bot.on.message(text=["бургер", "Бургер", "слава капитализм", "Слава капитализм", "я капиталист", "я капиталист", "чипсы", "Чипсы", "Я играю", "я играю", "я американец"])
async def hi_handler(message: Message):


    users_info = await bot.api.users.get(message.from_id)
    await message.answer("Капиталист дьявол машина",  "photo-208523444_457239770")

bot.run_forever()
```

**Как сделать чтобы он отвечал когда сообщение содержит фразу, а не равно ей (через in не получается)?**